# Call ccTouchesBegan when i touch a ccMenuItem without overriding the ccMenuItem class

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Is it possible to let the system call ccTouchesBegan of the ccLayer on moving on a CCMenuItem element without overriding the CCMenuItem class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a target delegate to layer with touch priority less then menu touch priority.

Sample code is below :

```
int touchPriority = 0;

CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this,
    touchPriority ,
    true);

CCMenu* menu= CCMenu::create();
menu->setTouchPriority(touchPriority + 1);
```

Comment: I tryed to set touchPriority to 0 on the CCLayer and touchPriority 1 on the CCMenu but the result is that now the CCLayer OnTouches event never fires at all now, only the CCMenu touches as before but not the CCMenuItems. Tryed inverting priority 0 with 1 . The same result.

Comment: Ok. I managed to get this code work putting it in the OnLoad function of the CCLayer class and not in the Init. Suppose that in Objective-C Load and Init are constructors and Create or something like that. Now the onTouches fires. Still not managed to get the CCLayer to get the touch when moving on the CCMenuItems.

Comment: I'm sorry. It doesn't depend from the event, Create and constructor actually. The CCLayer do not get the touches at all.

Comment: I had to add the TargetedDelegate to the CCMenu too for some reasons.

Comment: It may depend upon how did you implemented layers and menus but I did answered simplest solution.